# Create a new column for set of values by multiple conditions

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, datatable

Let's say I have a data table:

```
> a<-data.table(col1=c(7,85,1905,22,250))
   col1
1:    7
2:   85
3: 1905
4:   22
5:  250
```

I would like to add a new column in the same data table, considering these conditions condition:

```
if col1(i) <10 then "A"
else if col1(i) <100 then "B"
else if col1(i) <1000 then "C"
else "D"
```

So, I'd obtain

```
   col1 col2
1:    7    A
2:   85    B
3: 1905    D
4:   22    B
5:  250    C
```

I have tried the `ifelse` method but it puts "A" in all columns, and `doc` says that this method works only on first element of the vector it uses.

`dt[, col2 := ifelse(col1 < 10,'A','B')]`

I don't want to use complex and long loops to do that so if somebody can explain how it works in `R`, I'd be thankful.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cut` is a good option for you, this way you avoid using nested `ifelse`s

```
> a[, col2:=cut(a$col1, 
                breaks=c(-Inf,10,100,1000,Inf), 
                include.lowest = TRUE, 
                labels=c("A", "B", "C", "D"))]
> a
   col1 col2
1:    7    A
2:   85    B
3: 1905    D
4:   22    B
5:  250    C
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you Jilbert

Comment: I wondered how to do the same with a vector of `characters`, so I thought about converting to a `factor` then to a `numeric`. for instance return `1` if `a`,`2` if `b`, `3` if `c`, `4` if anything else: `a[, col2:=as.numeric(cut(as.numeric(as.factor(col1)), breaks=c(-Inf,1,2,3,Inf), include.lowest = TRUE, labels=c(1, 2, 3, 4)))]`. `col1 col2`
`1:    a    1`
`2:    b    2`
`3:    c    3`
`4:    d    4`
`5:    e    4`. is there a better way to do that?